# Find the derivative of $h(r)=(ae^r) / (b + e^r)$.

Tags: derivatives

I got this answer 
$$\frac{ae^r(b-1)}{(b + e^r)^2}.$$
But in the solution page, they put the answer 
$$\frac{abe^r}{ (b + e^r)^2}.$$

Which is the correct answer? There answer is correct if $d/dx(b) = 0$, I thought it's $1$.

Comment: $h(r)=(ae^r) / (b + e^r)$?

Comment: check now, I got typo mistake

Answer (score 1):

According to the [quotient's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule), the derivative $h'(x)$ should be equal to
$$\frac{(ae^r)'(b+e^r)-(ae^r)(b+e^r)'}{(b+e^r)^2}=\frac{ae^r(b+e^r)-(ae^r)(0+e^r)}{(b+e^r)^2}.$$
Can you take it from here? Did you find your mistake?

Comment: why, $(b+e^r)'$ = $(0 + e^4)$                I thought it should be $(1 + e^4)$

Comment: The derivative of a constant, i.e. $b$, is zero.

Comment: thanks I get it now

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this uses $h-a=\frac{-ab}{b+e^r}\implies h^\prime=\frac{abe^r}{(b+e^r)^2}$. This approach replaces the quotient rule with the chain rule.